# Ionic page only needs to load data from http request once

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, httprequest, loading

So currently I'm building an ionic app, and on my main page layout I will be displaying some elements that I got from an Http Get Request.

I have two problems that I'm facing right now:

1) **The page got rendered before my Httprequest returns** , thus I got a very weird layout until a few seconds kick in and the page finishes loading my images. Is there any way to render the entire page only after the http request returns? I have used the LoadingController module but so far it's not working for me.

2) Every time I need to **go back to main page**, it will need to call the http request and **I have to wait** for everything to get loaded again. Is there anyway that I can prevent this and got my main page to fetch the data only once.

Any opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo make the request on ngOnInit()